# Making a canvas (or img) stretch as much as much as possible within a grid (without overflowing) while preserving aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, canvas, grid

I would like to create matplotlib-like plotting utility using HTML. See the following image for an example:
[image: Example]
The plot should contain a canvas in which the result will be drawn, axis labels, a title and a colorbar. The canvas should be stretched as much as possible within the parent, while preserving aspect ratio.
The colorbar should be the same height as the canvas and have min and max values below and above it.
I am having trouble making it stretch when it still has available space.

The most appropriate solution for this seems to be CSS `grid`, however I have also experimented with `flex` and `table`.
I have created a simplified [codepen](https://codepen.io/m-mezulis/pen/vYVxpgE) to demonstrate the furthest I have gotten.
It functions as I expect when the canvas is larger than the container - the canvas is shrinked using `min-width: 0; min-height: 0`, however when it is smaller than the available space for it, it is not stretched and I cannot find a CSS property that would make it stretch.

Another solution I have considered is drawing everything inside a canvas, however in the future I will also want to make the upper and lower bounds inputs so that the user can change the range of the colorbar.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by preserving aspect ratio if the canvas is to stretch? Which direction is it to stretch in? Or are you looking for something like object-fit: contain where one of width or height is filled but aspect-ratio is maintained

Comment: @AHaworth It should stretch in all directions, yes, something like `object-fit: contain`, however so that the grid element does not have padding, if that makes sense. The issue with `object-fit: contain` was that the colorbar would be higher than the canvas if it the canvas is very wide, or there would be lots of space between the colorbar and the plot if it is very high.
In the codepen I linked the last three sizing options are where the canvas is not being stretched, and the first three are what they should look like.

Comment: If it stretches in both directions how can it maintain its aspect ratio?

Comment: @AHaworth It should stretch in both directions in the sense that it should stretch vertically, if there is vertical space available, and horizontally if there is horizontal space available. If it is maxed out in either of these directions, then it should not increase in size anymore.

Comment: So contain is what you need.

Comment: @AHaworth Unfortunately that does not solve the problem and has the problems I mentioned in the first comment. Please see this adjusted codepen: https://codepen.io/m-mezulis/pen/ExdELmz
I have filled in the canvas in black to indicate the spacing issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253589/discussion-between-mrtis-mezulis-and-a-haworth).